# Create a filesystem like mkfs.ext3 in perl

Tags: linux, image, perl, filesystems

I have an empty image-file with the size of 1GB, where I want to create a filesystem.

I've tried the command `/sbin/mkfs.ext3 -F MyImage.img`, and it worked, but has anyone an idea how to do it by perl code, not by calling a system funcion?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/guestfs-perl